# Unwanted desktop processes started by systemd at ssh login

Tags: ssh, systemd, login, pulseaudio, d-bus

When I ssh to my media server, I get a bunch of unrequested processes started up:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user
/usr/bin/dbus-broker-launch --scope user
dbus-broker
/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal
```

Surely you'd only want pulseaudio and dbus if you're starting a GUI session.

I can kill systemd and those processes also die - it doesn't seem to hurt anything in my ssh session.

Whats worse, is that these processes don't die when I log out.

How do I stop this?

I can do

```
systemctl --user disable pulseaudio.service dbus-broker.service
```

... but I would need these if I do a GUI login (eg on the monitor or in a headless sway session).

I would have thought that SYSADMINS around the world would be seizing their pitchforks and marching on Castle Systemd in anger at spurious processes being created by simple ssh logins - and worse still, leaving them running when logged out.

This is on fedora-33

Comment: Sysadmins got more important things to worry about than 2 processes using barely any resources

Comment: Related: [What does pam_systemd.so do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/626665/what-does-pam-systemd-so-do)

Comment: @Panki - I beg to differ. Imagine (as in my previous employer) 1000's of linux VM instances, dozens of ops staff, possibly hundreds of automated ssh jobs - it adds up. I admit that for me on my home setup, it's just an untidiness; a lack of minimalism. As a Unix greybeard, I hate that and I'm suspicious of what these youngsters are doing with systemd!

Comment: @steeldriver - thanks for the useful link which led me to remove the pam_systemd.so line from /etc/pam.d/system-auth. Now I can log in without the cruft. Next, I need to find out how to prepare such a login for a GUI session - should I want one!! Running 'systemd --user' doesn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

The starting of a user session is caused by invocation of `pam_systemd.so` (on debian systems, this is in `/etc/pam.d/common-session` which is referenced by a line `@include common-session` in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`).

Put `UsePAM no` in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to prevent `sshd` from using the whole **Pluggable Authentication Modules** mechanism `systemd` hooks into.

Alternatively, you could comment out just the mentioned `@include common-session` line in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`.

Comment: Unfortunately, fedora has a very different PAM setup and /etc/ssh/sshd_config has a comment "# WARNING: 'UsePAM no' is not supported in Fedora and may cause several
# problems."